# Delphi ComboBox control OnDrawDataCell position with master / child grid

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

In my Delphi application I have two grids. When the user selects a record from the top grid, the records are filtered in the lower grid.

I've attempted to implement a dropdown control inside the lower grid, which enumerates items from a TStringList. I set it's position OnDrawDataCell:

```
procedure TfrmPieces.grdPiecedtlDrawDataCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
if (gdFocused in State) then
begin
if (Field.FieldName = 'Vendors') then
with cboVendors do
begin
  Left := Rect.Left + grdPiecedtl.Left + 1;
  Top := Rect.Top + grdPiecedtl.Top + 1;
  Width := Rect.Right - Rect.Left + 2;
  Width := Rect.Right - Rect.Left + 2;
  Height := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top + 2;
end;
```

end
end;

I have also implemented hiding the control on col exit and showing and hiding the control on cell changed.

The problem is this: If I select a record in the top grid that has 3 rows, and I select the column in row 3 the combobox's position is maintained. I hide the combo box (at present) on row changed of the upper grid but, when I click in column 1 of the newly refreshed lower grid, it shows the dropdown in the old position. If I click out of the field and back into it in row 1 it then repositions fine, but that initial row change is causing a problem. I tried to redraw the grid on row change but that has no effect.

I appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything related to a custom control here.

Comment: Why are you doing this with a separate combobox instead of using the DBGrid.Column.PickList, which does all of this work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. While the picklist was not available for my specific grid control, I ended up finding one that did and went that direction instead.